# How was Coming to America received in the black community?

Tags: reception, coming-to-america

As a kid, I enjoyed *Coming to America* immensely. Rewatching it as an adult, it occurred to me that it's one of the first films I can think of with an almost all black cast, almost all in empowering roles (as opposed to blaxploitation, for instance, where only the hero protagonist had a positive role).

We see an African kingdom, rich and prosperous. We see Mr. Cleo McDowell, a successful restaurant owner with his two daughters.

Was this film at the time received as I in hindsight think it may have been?

How was it received in the black community?

Comment: This is a little broad. It might be better to limit the scope to detail what proof of reception you might need.

Comment: I'm not asking for the opinions of the users of this Stack, I'm asking for the opinions _of the black community_ (at the time, or in retrospect). Asking _about_ an opinion is not asking _for_ an opinion and is not "opinion-based".

Comment: There's even a tag for questions about how a film was received.

Answer (score 1):

Digging around in ProQuest (an index of newspaper headlines, among other things), I came across the following reference:

> Briscoe, Stephen (04/22/1992). "'Coming to America' in Class? If It's Done Right, Teachers Say". Michigan Chronicle,  p. A1.
>   
>  
>   **Abstract:**  The controversy over whether the film "Coming to America" should have been shown to a class of fourth graders in Detroit is examined.

The *Michigan Chronicle* is a Detroit newspaper that is operated by and aimed at African-Americans, so I suspect that this article might give you a sense of the various opinions on the film in the African-American community around the time of its release.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find a full text of this article online;  so I'm making this answer into a community wiki.  If anyone is able to dig up the full text, I would be interested to see some pertinent excerpts from this article added in.